# Laravel blade set value on input with ternary if

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, conditional-operator

I have a template that change the style if into an input is set the "value" attribute or not, even if it is empty.

For example this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="">
```

is different for the template from this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
```

For this reason I need to check with a ternary if, if the value is set or not.

I wrote this code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" {{ (isset($category) ? ("value='".$category->name."'") : "") }}>
```

But when I run the page, and the `$category` variable is set, I find into the input a value like this: `'Category`

I checked code generated and I can find this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="'Category" a="" name&#039;="">
```

But the value in the DB is `Category name`.

Could you please help me to find the issue?

Comment: Isn’t it the same way? What do you suggest? `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" @if (isset($category)) {{ "value='".$category->name."'" }} @endif>`

Comment: this sounds good! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a ternary operator it is not needed in this case, since you will do nothing in case condition result `false`.

You can use just `@if`:

```
@if (isset($category)) value="{{$category->name}}" @endif
```

Also, there is an `@isset` directive, so could be more appropriate if you do:

```
@isset($category) value="{{$category->name}}" @endisset
```

In your input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" @isset($category) value="{{$category->name}}" @endisset />
```

---

Ref: Blade Directives [If Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements).

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do this;

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ isset($category) ? $category->name : '' }}" >
```

Comment: No because if the result is null, it will print `value=“”`

Comment: So? If it print value="" it means it will be empty.

Comment: No, as explained in my main topic, for the template is different.